# Change the color of specific letters in UITableView index alphabet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to change the color of specific letter in my UITableview to show that this section is empty. For example, if there are entries for the letter 'a' but not for 'b', I want the letter 'b' to appear, but be black, while the letter 'a' is red.

I know it can be done for the entire alphabet this way:

```
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"]) {
        [view performSelector:@selector(setIndexColor:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
```

but can a single letter's color be changed?

Comment: That is not the proper way to change the colors of the index. `UITableView` actually provides public APIs for setting the colors. Of course it affects all letters but don't use the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it directly. You need to subclass it.

Check out this [github](https://github.com/CraigMerchant/CMIndexBar) project. It does exactly that: